# How to retain commit ssh passphrase for 1 hour?

Tags: git, gpg-signature

I have added this option to my `.gitconfig`

```
[commit]
  gpgsign = true
```

But Git asks me for my passphrase each time I do a commit. I don't want to create a new keypair with an empty passphrase. I rather would like Git to retain my passphrase for few hours.

Is it that possible?

Comment: Sttrange, why are you using cygwin? Between WSL and a regular git bash, Cygwin should be obsolete by now... I am used to start ssh-agent in the .bashrc. gpg-agent should work too.

Comment: @VonC It is not because from WSL you 1. Must be on Windows 10, 2. You cannot access the linux fs from Windows, 3. The clipboard `/dev/clipboard` doesn't work on WSL, 4. Unable to call WSL programs from Windows (integration with Eclipse, Netbeans, ...). So I am afraid, Cygwin itn't yet obsolete.

Comment: btw, I get this error `gpg: gpg-agent is not available in this session`

Comment: And git bash? You can use the regular clip.exe in it.

Comment: @VonC, with git bash you can't have access to gcc, perl, sl. I have a Linux spirit, but I am forced to work on Windows. Cygwin gives me a nice alternative until WSL matches my requirements

Comment: OK. I guess that leaves you with docker then: your own lightweight virtual machine, with the Linux distribution of your choice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155691/discussion-between-nowox-and-vonc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gpg: gpg-agent is not available in this session
```

As mention here, that might be because `gpg-agent --version` and `gpg --version` differ.
Double-check your `$PATH`: you might find a gpg.exe in one folder, and a `gpg-agent` in another.

Plus, gpg-agent should work with gpg2, and you are using gpg 1...
See "[how to install gpg on cygwin? currently it's missing](https://superuser.com/a/1207635/141)".

Comment: You're right about this `gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.22`, `gpg-agent (GnuPG) 2.1.23-unknown`

Comment: Both executables are located into `/usr/bin/` though

Comment: @nowox Where are they located? See the output of `which gpg`, `which gpg-agent`. Maybe, even though they are both in `/usr/bin`, the `$PATH` make one visible elsewhere before the other.

Comment: @nowox maybe this is a gpg-agent for gpg2 and you are using gpg 1... Although, I wonder where that gpg-agent is coming from (https://superuser.com/a/1050294/141)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [gpg-agent](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html) that way you can just type your password once.

> gpg-agent is a daemon to manage secret (private) keys independently from any protocol.

If using mac os you could use https://gpgtools.org/ and store the password in the keychain.

From the [GitHub docs](https://help.github.com/articles/signing-commits-using-gpg/), check the tips section:

```
To store your GPG key passphrase so you don't have to enter it every 
time you sign a commit, we recommend using the following tools:

For Mac users, the GPG Suite allows you to store your GPG key 
passphrase in the Mac OS Keychain.

For Windows users, the Gpg4win integrates with other Windows tools.

You can also manually configure gpg-agent to save your GPG key 
passphrase, but this doesn't integrate with Mac OS Keychain like
ssh-agent and requires more setup.
```

Comment: I am on Cygwin and I have `gpg-agent`: `gpg-agent[142248]: gpg-agent running and available`. Unfortunately Git asks me for my passphrase each time

Comment: probably this can give you some ideas: https://gist.github.com/bmhatfield/cc21ec0a3a2df963bffa3c1f884b676b basically ensures the agent is up per shell